# Precision issue in reverse coordinate transformation between latitude and normalised Mercator y-coordinates in C# (SuperCluster Mapbox)

Tags: c#, math, geometry, mercator, supercluster

I have implemented two functions `LatY` and `YLat`  that converts a given **latitude** value to a normalized **Mercator y-coordinate** value and vice versa. The **`LatY`** function uses the following formula:

```
double LatY(double lat)
{
    var sin = Math.Sin(lat * Math.PI / 180);
    
    var y = 0.5 - 0.25 * Math.Log((1 + sin) / (1 - sin)) / Math.PI;

    return y;
}
```

And the **`YLat`** function uses the following formula:

```
double YLat(double y)
{
    var exp = -(Math.PI / 0.25) * (y - 0.5);

    var antiLog = Math.Pow(10, exp);

    var sin = (antiLog - 1) / (antiLog + 1);

    var lat2 = Math.Asin(sin) * (180 / Math.PI);
    return lat2;
}
```

However, when I tested the functions by converting a latitude value to y using LatY and then back to latitude using YLat, the result was not the same as the original latitude value. For example:

```
var y = LatY(-112.484379);
var lat = YLat(y);
```

The expected value of **`lat`** should be **`-112.484379`**, but the calculated value is **`-87.22371494918505`**.

I suspect that the precision issue may be causing this problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Can anyone provide some insights on what might be causing this issue and how to address it?

I was expecting that the calculated latitude value would be the same as the original latitude value. However, the result was not as expected, and there was a significant difference between the expected and actual values.

**Note:** I have also tried it in JavaScript but facing the same problem.

Comment: I have also tried these different forms of **`YLat`**

`
double YLat(double y)
{
         var y2 = (1 - y * 2) * Math.PI;
         return 360f * Math.Atan(Math.Exp(y2)) / Math.PI - 90f;
}
`

Comment: How can you have -112 degrees when the north South Poles are at 90 degrees?  A Mercator projection is a rectangular map of the globe. As everybody learned in elementary school the latitude are large as you get to the poles.  Try casting values to a double to get more accurate results.  Never use VAR unless you absolutely have to like in Linq expressions.  You are letting the compile convert to float instead of double where you would get better accuracy with a double.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for letting me know about the issue. I was passing incorrect values to function. Rather than passing the latitude value to **`LatY ()`** I was passing the longitude value. Passing the correct latitude value solved my issue.